# MVC Attribute Routing adding Area Querystring Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've tried adding the Route attribute to our controller through various methods.

```
[Route("Trials/{trialId:int}/Components/{action}")]
public partial class ComponentsController : Controller
{
    public virtual ActionResult List(int trialId)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Or

```
[RoutePrefix("Trials/{trialId:int}/Components")]
[Route("{action=List}")]
public partial class ComponentsController : Controller
{
    public virtual ActionResult List(int trialId)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

are just a few examples.

The links generated going to this controller/action look like this:

http://localhost:50077/Trials/3/Components?Area=

I'm looking to remove the query string parameter.  No matter how I place the route configuration with attributes, it never seems to work.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "TrialComponents",
        //    url: "Trials/{trialId}/Components/{action}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new {controller = "Components", action = "List", area = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
        //    constraints: new { trialId = "\\d+"}
        //);

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "UnitGroups", action = "List", area = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

The commented out route works and does not apply a querystring to the url.

Can anyone explain why the route method is adding the Area querystring and how I can fix it?  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Area is not a route value that is stored in the `RouteData.Values` collection, it is instead found on the `RouteData.DataTokens` collection (as metadata). It is not correct to set a default for `area` in your `RouteCollection` because this only gets applied to `RouteData.Values` of the request.

In short, to remove the `Area` parameter from your generated URLs, you need to remove it as a default value in your `MapRoute`.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "UnitGroups", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: I got around to trying this today, but its still the same.  I still have Area= as a querystring.